# How to include links in HTTPNotFound errors in Pyramid?

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, pyramid, html-escape-characters

One part of my site is a wiki engine. When a page does not exist I want to provide a custom 404 error page containing a link to create a new page. This custom 404 should only be seen in the context of a failed wiki page view.

To implement this logic I simply return (not raise) a HTTPNotFound() object with a custom message containing a link for the new page creation. Unfortunately the links are escaped.
How can I force the html links to appear as links ?

**Edit**:
I found a solution form [Python Pyramid & Chameleon templating language escapes html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346295/python-pyramid-chameleon-templating-language-escapes-html)

```
class Literal:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
    def __html__(self):
        return self.s
```

It's very likely that such an object already exists in Pyramid

Comment: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/hooks.html#changing-the-not-found-view
it looks like you can create a custom `not_found` view where you can render a template.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815224/pyramid-custom-404-page-returns-as-200-ok

Comment: @dm03514 yes but this will make things more complex. For example I only want this custom 404 view to be called when a wiki page is not found (ie does not exist yet), and another default 404 page in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not Found views in Pyramid accept the same predicates as regular views.

```
config.add_route('wiki', '/wiki/{page}')

@notfound_view_config()
def notfound_view(exc, request):
    """ Generic notfound view for the entire site."""
    return exc

@notfound_view_config(route_name='wiki')
def wiki_notfound_view(exc, request):
    """ Specific notfound for urls matching the wiki pattern."""
    return exc
```

As far as your escaping issue, that's specific to your templating language. In mako you would use `${ msg | n }` and in jinja2 you would use `{{ msg | safe }}` to turn off auto-escaping on the string.